# How to embed the date-to-timestamp conversion in a mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, timestamp, date-conversion

Suppose I have documents in a mongo collections with a timestamp field. I want to query the documents based on the timestamp value (greater than, less than). In order to do that, instead of calculating each time the timestamp for my current date, I would like to embed the conversion from the date to timestamp in the query. I tried something like this (suppose `"ts"` is my timestamp field):

```
db.my_collection.find({"ts": {$lt: {$toLong : new Date("2020-12-09")}}})
```

instead of doing:

```
db.my_collection.find({"ts": {$lt: 1578524400}})
```

but it seems to return an empty result.

Is there a result to perform the date-to-timestamp conversion inside the query?

Comment: Do it on app/shell level: `db.my_collection.find({"ts": {$lt: new Date("2020-12-09").getTime()/1000 }})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$toLong` but it's an aggregation pipeline operator, you need an aggregation pipeline not a plain `find`.